# Using Illustrator .ai files in a Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, macos, adobe-illustrator

I have a client inquiring about developing a Cocoa application that would open Illustrator files.  How viable is this in your opinion?  How closed is the format?  I can't seem to find any useful information on Adobe's site.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Speaking of Adobe formats, this code comment in an open source app is classic: http://fallenpegasus.livejournal.com/854615.html

Comment: ...but .ai format is good. ;-)

Comment: Disregarding the fact that this question was half my career ago almost and is getting down voted in 2015, how can it be made any narrower in retrospect?  I think this was exactly what I meant to ask at the time.

Comment: @diatrevolo I think that you needed to reword it in a way that made it seem like you were trying to do something concrete.  Something like this....  am trying to write an OSX application that can open an Illustrator file and draw what is there on the screen.  I'm a newbie and haven't tried anything yet, please can anyone point me in the direction of how to get started?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modern ai files are PDF files (CS3 thru CS5) with application specific comments. Adobe Illustrator will ignore the actual PDF data when opening an ai file and just use the comments it inserted when writing it.

Comment: Up-vote for very good information. Can you edit your answer to include a source?

Answer (score 1):

Simply to open it? Quite viable. NSImage will load it as a rasterized image without blinking an eye. Treat it as any other supported image file when creating an NSImage instance.

If you want to be able to examine its internals (like layers, paths, etc.) and possibly edit, then I don't know of any open-source Objective-C libraries for doing this.

Comment: Right, it smells like using EPS might be the better option...thanks for the insight.